# Attempting to run find command gives "Permission denied"

Tags: macos, applications, bash, command-line

I am attempting to obtain a list of applications on my Mac using `find` to search for `*.app`. However, when running the command, I get a lot of Permission denied messages, as below.

The computer is mine and I have administrative access. How can I run the command without the errors?

```
Last login: Thu Jul 17 07:42:01 on ttys000
pamelas-mbp:~ pamelabohler-sampson$ find / -iname *.app > ~/applications.txt
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.MobileBackups: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
find: /Library/Application Support/Apple/ParentalControls/Users: Permission denied
find: /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Permission denied
find: /Library/Caches/com.apple.Spotlight/schema.201.plist: Permission denied
[...]
find: /private/var/spool/postfix/private: Permission denied
find: /private/var/spool/postfix/public: Permission denied
find: /private/var/spool/postfix/saved: Permission denied
find: /private/var/spool/postfix/trace: Permission denied
find: /private/var/tmp/launchd: Permission denied
find: /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.coresymbolicationd: Permission denied
find: /System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default: Permission denied
```

Comment: `sudo find / -iname *.app 2>/dev/null > ~/applications.txt` for example, this will not write `/dev/fd/4` to the file. Standard error is overlooked, stout it piped directly into txt file.You may be better off with `sudo find .`...etc, or creating a locate db `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` , then `locate [string--see help for further options]`

Comment: I would run that as `sudo find / -iname *app 2>/dev/null > ~/applications.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You need to be root to access certain system directories. Prepend your command with `sudo`:

```
sudo find / -iname *.app > ~/applications.txt
```

This will give a prompt for your password:

```
Password:
```

Enter your password (the characters will not be shown), then press Enter. The find command will then be run as root and have access to the directories.

Answer (score 2):

You get those messages because as a normal User You don't have permissions to view directories listed. For example `/.fseventsd` is owned by root and only root can access it (`drwx------  587 root  wheel`). To get root privilages You have to run Your command with `sudo`. In Your case it'll be:

```
sudo find / -iname *.app > ~/applications.txt
```